# Add row number of first time interval to its consecutive time intervals in dplyr or sql

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I have a data like this:

```
a = data.frame( id = c(1:5),
                time_left = c('2010-01-04', '2010-02-15', 
                              '2010-03-01', '2010-03-08', 
                              '2010-03-15'), 
                time_right = c('2010-01-28', '2010-03-02', 
                               '2010-03-07', '2010-03-14', 
                               '2010-03-23'))
```

I need to find the id of the first time interval for its consecutive time intervals. My main data set is too large and I need an efficient solution.

Here are the input and my desired output:

input:

```
id  time_left time_right
1   2010-01-04 2010-01-28
2   2010-02-15 2010-03-02
3   2010-03-01 2010-03-07
4   2010-03-08 2010-03-14
5   2010-03-15 2010-03-23
```

output:

```
id  time_left time_right   group_id
1   2010-01-04 2010-01-28   1
2   2010-02-15 2010-03-02   1
3   2010-03-01 2010-03-07   3
4   2010-03-08 2010-03-14   3
5   2010-03-15 2010-03-23   3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:sql]? Is this a table in a database? If so, which DBMS?

Comment: For using sqldf::sqldf which I guess you wrote the solution. Thanks

Comment: @r2evans Is it possible to modify this code to handle un-arrangable consecutive dates like: input = data.frame(time_left = c("2016-01-01", "2016-09-05", "2016-09-06","2016-09-08", "2016-09-12","2016-09-15"), time_right = c("2016-09-07", "2016-09-11", "2016-09-12", "2016-09-14", "2016-09-18","2016-09-21")); output = data.frame(  id = c(1:6) ,time_left = c("2016-01-01", "2016-09-05", "2016-09-06","2016-09-08", "2016-09-12","2016-09-15"), time_right = c("2016-09-07", "2016-09-11", "2016-09-12", "2016-09-14", "2016-09-18","2016-09-21"), group_id=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1) )

Comment: the logic to apply on that `input` eludes me: everything overlaps, and it isn't clear how one "knows" which overlap is relevant where

Comment: @r2evans Lets say only consider those records that time_right = time_left - 1, the day difference is equal to one.

Comment: Row-wise, nothing meets that condition, so you must be thinking "any" time_right = "any" time_left - 1. Sorry, I don't understand how your new grouping is supposed to work.

Comment: sorry that I could not explain clearly. In the new input, time_right[1] = time_left[4]-1, and time_right[4] = time_left[4] - 1. The group_id for these records should be one ( the first record for this chain).

Comment: This can explode, since instead of comparing against consecutive rows, you must compare against _all_ rows. If your data is not big then you can do this without exhausting memory or run-time. It seems like you are trying to find a longest sequence (right-to-left) between rows, and once that is complete, rerun with the remaining rows for the next group, etc. The premise is mentioned https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/09/compute-longest-increasingdecreasing-subsequence-using-rcpp/, but it's not right for this. I cannot work on this atm.

Answer (score 0):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  group_by(group_id = c(0L, cumsum(time_left[-1] < time_right[-n()]))) %>%
  mutate(group_id = first(id)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      id time_left  time_right group_id
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>         <int>
# 1     1 2010-01-04 2010-01-28        1
# 2     2 2010-02-15 2010-03-02        1
# 3     3 2010-03-01 2010-03-07        3
# 4     4 2010-03-08 2010-03-14        3
# 5     5 2010-03-15 2010-03-23        3
```

### sql

```r
sqldf::sqldf(
  "with cte1 as (
     select *, (case when time_left > lag(time_right) over (order by id) then 0 else 1 end) as grp
     from a
   ),
   cte2 as (
     select *, sum(cte1.grp) over (order by cte1.id) as group_number
     from cte1
   ),
   cte3 as (
     select cte2.id, cte2.time_left, cte2.time_right,
       min(cte2.group_number) as group_number
     from cte2
     group by group_number
   )
   select cte2.id, cte2.time_left, cte2.time_right, cte3.id as group_id
   from cte2
     left join cte3 on cte2.group_number = cte3.group_number")
```